# Mysql update concatenated variables

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have the following code in PHP in Magento that tries to insert a concatenated value in a specific file into one table

```
    $extencion = '.jpg';
    $test ='/small/';
    $_prodId= 1;

   $conn  = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

$sql = "update catalog_product_entity_varchar
        set value = ".$test.$_prodId.$extencion."
        where entity_id = ".$_prodId."
        and attribute_id  = 86 ";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

I tried by concatenating the value before the update

```
$concatenate = $test.$_prodId.$extencion;
```

But no success, any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to insert string into quotes :

```
$sql = "update catalog_product_entity_varchar
    set value = '".$test.$_prodId.$extencion."'
    where entity_id = ".$_prodId."
    and attribute_id  = 86 ";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $extencion = '.jpg';
    $test ='/small/';
    $_prodId= 1;

    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $adapter = $resource->getConnection('write');

    $bind = array(
        'value' => $test.$_prodId.$extencion
    );

    $where = array(
        'entity_id = ?'     => $_prodId,
        'attribute_id = ?'  => 86
    );

    $adapter->update($resource->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_varchar'), $bind, $where);
```